# C code, using NULL versus 0, Best Practices

Tags: c, null

In C coding, when is it best to use "NULL" versus 0. 
I have noticed in code that wherever there is a pointer, NULL is used.

Comment: The answers of the duplicate mentions the "difference" between NULL and 0 as well, so it seems appropriate as a duplicate. At least considering that "best practices" is opinion-based, i.e. not appropriate for [so].

Answer (score 0):

When initializing variables you should use:

```
int i=0;
float f=0.0f;
double = 0.0;
char c='\0';
```

In the case of initializing pointers, you should use NULL in any kind of pointer. This is due to the definition of pointer type variable: it doesn't hold a value, it holds the address of a value, or set of values(array/string -> int in case of int* (array), char in case of char* (string), etc.). Therefore you use NULL to indicate that it points to nothing on the memory.

Comment: Pointers still hold values. In the case of `NULL`, it's the value of 0 typed as a pointer.

Comment: Important note to what @JonathanWood said: `NULL` (or `(T*)0`) is not necessarily all-0 in memory.